# Expressing Spin State |r> As Linear Superposition of |u> and |d>: Basic Linear Algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

**Background**
[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/244496/109063), from **Quantum Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum** started with the following assumption(?)

$$|r\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|u\rangle + \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}|d\rangle$$

I'm now attempting to derive(?) the above based on the initial information given, which I think, based on [the paragraph immediately above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaIEe.jpg), is as follows:

$$|r\rangle = x|u\rangle + y|d\rangle$$
and
$$\langle r|u\rangle \langle u|r\rangle = \frac{1}{2}$$
and
$$\langle r|d\rangle \langle d|r\rangle = \frac{1}{2}$$

**Questions**

1. Is my assumption about the initial information correct?
2. If #1 is 'yes' would solving the above be covered in basic linear algebra?

**NOTE:** Please do **not** provide a solution to the set of equations.

Comment: Yes and yes. This is exactly what you learn in linear algebra when you learn about basis decomposition.

Comment: @knzhou Thanks. And I was afraid you were going to say that.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, the state is a soverposition, with amplitudes x and y still to define, of the eigenstates up and down.
2. You would just impose normalization for the state |r>, by performing a scalar product of |r> with itself. Also, you want the two probabilities to be the same ,i.e. the two projections of the state |r> over the 2 basis vectors up and down are equal.

Comment: Why a and b and not x and y?  And, if possible to do so without making the answer incomplete, please remove the actual solution to the problem.

Comment: sorry i used a and b instead of x and y. but same thing

Comment: No problem. Just remove the solution to the problem when you get a chance.  Also, to clarify, the answer to #2 is "no", correct?

Comment: Also, are "normalization" and "scalar products"  (I'm not familiar with either) covered in linear algebra?

Comment: yes. normalization means that you want the lenght of the vector to be 1. A scalar product is the sum of the products of the components of two vectors... you should check it out somewhere.

Comment: So the solution to the problem IS covered in linear algebra?  Also, sis you see my suggestion for your answer?

Comment: yes it is. and yes i saw the suggestion, but that's part of the basic idea..otherwise you couldn't get to the solution. that's actually finding those projections